# HeapSort returns wrong array (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue, heapsort, max-heap

My HeapSort returns an array that is not in the correct order.
My original array is {15, 9, 11, 5, 6, 7}, and when run the heapSort method, I am getting this array: {15, 11, 9, 6, 7, 5}.

I printed the method to see what maxHeap did and got: {15, 9, 11, 5, 6, 7}, which when mapped out in a binary tree is actually a maxHeap. This makes me believe there is something wrong with either the sorting method or buildMaxHeap method.

```
    public class heaps
    {
    public void maxHeap(int arr[], int index, int n)
    {
    int largest = index;
    n = arr.length;
    int l = (2*index) + 1;
    int r =(2*index) + 2;
    int size = arr.length;                                  

    if ((l < n) && (arr[l] > arr[largest]))             
        {
            largest = l;
        }
    else 
        {
            largest = index;    
        }
    if ((r < size) && arr[r] > (arr[largest]))          
        {
            largest = r;
        }
    if (largest != index)
        {
            int temp = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[largest];
            arr[largest] = temp;
            maxHeap(arr, largest, n);
        }
}

public void buildMaxHeap(int arr[])
{
    int n = arr.length; 
    for (int index = (n / 2) - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        maxHeap(arr, index, n);
    }
}

public void sort(int arr[])
{
    int n = arr.length;
    buildMaxHeap(arr);

    for (int index = n - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        int temp = arr[0];
        arr[0] = arr[index];
        arr[index] = temp;
        n = n - 1;                      
        maxHeap(arr, index, 0);
    }   
}

public void printArray(int arr[]) 
{ 
    int n = arr.length; 
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); 
    System.out.println(); 
}

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    heaps o = new heaps();

    int array[] = {15, 9, 11, 5, 6, 7};

    heaps.sort(array);
    heaps.printArray(array);
    heaps.maxHeap(array, 0, array.length);
    heaps.printArray(array);
}      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your `maxHeap` method correctly, the `n` parameter is supposed to be the maximum index. That is, `maxHeap(arr, index, n)` should take the item at `arr[index]` and push it down the heap, but no further than `arr[n]`.

If that's true, then your error is in the second line of your `maxHeap` method:

```
n = arr.length;
```

You're overwriting the value of the `n` parameter that you passed.

You have this call in your `sort` method:

```
    maxHeap(arr, index, 0);
```

So you're telling `maxHeap` to push the item at `arr[index]` down, but not lower than `arr[0]`. Seems to me that's going to be a problem, because nothing will ever move.

You need to spend a little time carefully examining your code. Single-stepping with a debugger is a great help. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn.

Comment: I commented out the line and it didn't make a difference in output. I actually decided to print to the console the sorted array to see if it's in descending order, but I got `15, 11, 9, 6, 7, 5 ` as a result instead of `15, 11, 9, 7, 6, 5`. For some reason, the `sort` method skipped over sorting the 7 and 6 in the right order.

Comment: @JamieL. See my updated answer. There's another bug, this time in calling `maxHeap`.